# Error: module 'AppRoutingModule' is exported recursively by the module 'AppRoutingModule'

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I am building a angular application, everything was working fine till I imported and implemented the "Routing Module"

**Error Message**

[image]

I have gone through and don't think the following are possible problems:

- Syntax errors, like multiple commas and such
- Recursive calls

Code for Router Module:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes , RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { RecipesComponent } from './recipes/recipes.component';
import { ShoppingListComponent } from './shopping-list/shopping-list.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
 {path: 'recipes', component: RecipesComponent},
 {path: 'shopping-list', component: ShoppingListComponent},
   { path: '', redirectTo: 'recipes', pathMatch: 'full'},
   { path: '**', redirectTo: '/not-found'},
]

@NgModule({
 imports: [
  RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
 ],
 exports: [AppRoutingModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule{

}
```

Code for Root Component:

```html
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { RecipesComponent } from './recipes/recipes.component';
import { RecipeListComponent } from './recipes/recipe-list/recipe-list.component';
import { RecipeDetailComponent } from './recipes/recipe-detail/recipe-detail.component';
import { RecipeItemComponent } from './recipes/recipe-list/recipe-item/recipe-item.component';
import { ShoppingListComponent } from './shopping-list/shopping-list.component';
import { ShoppingEditComponent } from './shopping-list/shopping-edit/shopping-edit.component';
import { DropdownDirective } from './shared/dropdown.directive';
import { ShoppingListService } from './shopping-list/shopping-list.service';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    RecipesComponent,
    RecipeListComponent,
    RecipeDetailComponent,
    RecipeItemComponent,
    ShoppingListComponent,
    ShoppingEditComponent,
    DropdownDirective
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [ShoppingListService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are exporting the wrong module. Change `exports: [AppRoutingModule]` to `exports: [RouterModule]`.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to change:

```
exports: [AppRoutingModule]
```

to:

```
exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

export the RouterModule instead of  AppRoutingModule.

`exports: [RouterModule]`